# Pass CharSequenceArray into other Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, arraylist

Hello I have make a `CharSequenceArray` into an Activity and I want to pass it to another Activity using Intent.

This is my array

```
ArrayList<CharSequence> selectedingredients = new ArrayList<CharSequence>();
```

and I put in the Intent like this

```
i.putCharSequenceArrayListExtra("ingredients", selectedingredients);
```

Put in the other activity how can i retrieve it and save it again in an ArrayList?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your second Activity call:

```
ArrayList<CharSequence> selectedingredients = getIntent().getCharArrayListExtra("ingredients");
```